# Creating Build.FINGERPRINT on Android

Tags: android

Android documentation refers to [Build.FINGERPRINT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#FINGERPRINT) as a way to uniquely identify the build. I'd like to know how this property is generated. I'm compiling whole framework on my board and it's set by default to *unknown*. Another question is if Market uses this identifier as some kind of validation?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See [here](http://chall32.blogspot.com/2010/06/android-market-fingerprints-demystified.html) for an overview of Build.FINGERPRINT:

> android.os.Build.FINGERPRINT: A string
>   that uniquely identifies this build.
>   It SHOULD be reasonably
>   human-readable. It MUST follow this
>   template:
>
> $(BRAND)/$(PRODUCT)/$(DEVICE)/$(BOARD):$(VERSION.RELEASE)/$(ID)/$(VERSION.INCREMENTAL):$(TYPE)/$(TAGS)
>
> For example:
>   acme/mydevice/generic/generic:2.1-update1/ERC77/3359:userdebug/test-keys
>
> The fingerprint MUST NOT include
>   spaces. If other fields included in
>   the template above have spaces, they
>   SHOULD be replaced with the ASCII
>   underscore ("_") character in the
>   fingerprint.

I do know that you do need to have your platform [certified](http://source.android.com/faqs.html) (which yes, includes providing your fingerprint so that Market can display only those apps that your device is able to run) before being licensed to use the Market.

Answer (score 7):

```
build/core/Makefile:  BUILD_FINGERPRINT := $(PRODUCT_BRAND)/$(TARGET_PRODUCT)/$(TARGET_DEVICE):$(PLATFORM_VERSION)/$(BUILD_ID)/$(BUILD_NUMBER):$(TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT)/$(BUILD_VERSION_TAGS)
```

Comment: Please consider elaborating on your solution, rather than simply posting one line. You should explain what your solution means and how it answers/pertains to the original question.

Comment: I have seen the structure RivieraKid gave in the accepted answer documented elsewhere, but it does not seem to reflect reality, where $(BOARD) is not present. This answer does. For example, a [Nexus 5x build fingerprint](https://www.androiddevice.info/submission/38993/show): `google/bullhead/bullhead:6.0.1/MTC20F/3031278:user/release-keys` . I do not know if this is universal, but it seems to be what Google does with its own products, at least currently.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the recent AOSP remove the `$(BOARD)`

Now it looks like this:
`$(PRODUCT_BRAND)/$(TARGET_PRODUCT)/$(TARGET_DEVICE):$(PLATFORM_VERSION)/$(BUILD_ID)/$(BF_BUILD_NUMBER):$(TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT)/$(BUILD_VERSION_TAGS)`

https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:build/make/core/sysprop.mk;l=170?q=BUILD_FINGERPRINT%20:%3D%20$

build/make/core/sysprop.mk

```
# BUILD_FINGERPRINT is used used to uniquely identify the combined build and
# product; used by the OTA server.
ifeq (,$(strip $(BUILD_FINGERPRINT)))
  ifeq ($(strip $(HAS_BUILD_NUMBER)),false)
    BF_BUILD_NUMBER := $(BUILD_USERNAME)$$($(DATE_FROM_FILE) +%m%d%H%M)
  else
    BF_BUILD_NUMBER := $(file <$(BUILD_NUMBER_FILE))
  endif
  BUILD_FINGERPRINT := $(PRODUCT_BRAND)/$(TARGET_PRODUCT)/$(TARGET_DEVICE):$(PLATFORM_VERSION)/$(BUILD_ID)/$(BF_BUILD_NUMBER):$(TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT)/$(BUILD_VERSION_TAGS)
endif
```

So a correct fingerprint is like:

**Pixel**

```
google/shamu/shamu:5.1.1/LMY48Y/2364368:user/release-keys
```

**Samsung S9**

```
samsung/starqlteue/starqlteue:10/QP1A.190711.020/G960U1UEU9FUE4:user/release-keys
```

**Samsung S10**

```
samsung/beyond2qlteue/beyond2q:11/RP1A.200720.012/G975U1UEU5GUE4:user/release-keys
```