# Does Build.FINGERPRINT give different results on identical devices?

Tags: android

Thanks in advance.  I'm just wondering if Build.FINGERPRINT returns the same result on identical devices.  Please someone with two identical test phones if you could run the following.

```
Log.d("test", Build.FINGERPRINT);
```

Comment: According to this question/answer yes ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041665/creating-build-fingerprint-on-android .

Comment: I didn't get that it was different from that post.

Comment: If I understood correctly it will be the same for two identical phones running the same Android version/update manufacturer provides.